# Как создать в файл во внутренней директории Android приложения?

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять почему не создается файл в папке `files` внутренней директории приложения. Делаю по инструкции из Android Developers.

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "hello");

File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "hello");

File file = new File(getApplicationContext.getFilesDir(), "hello");
```

Файл не создается, пробовал по разному, никак. Через поток `FileOutputStream`, файл создается, но как создать файл используя класс `File`? И как создать файл в созданном своем каталоге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект типа `File` создать недостаточно. Еще надо заставить файловую систему записать файл в память: `file.createNewFile();`